# Twitter style like button using Angular Animations

Tags: angular, animation

Need some help in implementing Twitter style like button (as shown below) using Angular Animations modules. I'm not inclined to use any external package for this job.

Has anyone implemented this before for their app?

[image]

Comment: There is an example with html and css here https://codepen.io/robeen/pen/PbvJjy/

Comment: @HarisBouchlis - Thanks for taking time to respond. Your proposed solution doesn't use Angular Animations but it's worth investigating whether it can be constructed using Angular Animation feature.